# Java Reading a file line per line

Tags: java, file-io, io, bufferedreader, filereader

This is what my file looks like:

```
IDENTIFICATION::HARD::Should We appreciate Art?::Yes
MULTIPLECHOICE::HARD::Which of the FF is not an era of Art?::Bayutism::Digitalism,Somethingism,Retardism,Bayutism
IDENTIFICATION::HARD::What is Chris Browns Greatest Hit?::Rihanna
```

And I am reading the file like this

```
public void openQBankFile(){
    try{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(qbank.getAbsolutePath()));
        String desc;
        while((desc = in.readLine()) != null){
            qbank_cont.add(desc);
        }

        in.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        System.out.println("Question Repository Could Not Be Found");
        return;
    }catch(IOException ioe){
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This where I get the contents of the arrayList

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        CreateQuiz cq = new CreateQuiz(new File("./quiz/HUM101.quiz"),new File("./qbank/HUM101.qbank"));
        cq.openQBankFile();
        cq.filterQuestions(3, "HARD");
        System.out.println(cq.qbank_cont.get(0));
    }
```

And this is how I add it

```
public void filterQuestions(int numOfItems, String difficulty){
        List<String> qt_diff = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i< qbank_cont.size();i++){
            qt_diff.add(qbank_cont.get(i));
        }
    }
```

And I will store it inside an `arrayList`. but when I store it in arraylist it will just insert the whole text. Not Line per line.  (I am using `arrayList.get(0)`)

Comment: Something's not right. The code you're using to read in the file appears as if it should work OK. Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) so that we can experience the problem and work on its solution ourselves.

Comment: Are you sure the lines in the file end with `\n`?

Comment: What makes you think its not working ? Can you post the code you use to get the list elements?

Comment: Okay, so it worked. what I did was replace the File quiz. to an absolute File Path. But I have no idea  why is it s behaving like that

Comment: @user962206 As has been pointed, the directory `.` is your working directory, the one where you are at when you launch your program. Hard-coding absolute paths in code in not a good idea. You may want to pass in the file names through command line options (i.e., the `String[] args` array).

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem seems to be that you don't understand how Java deals with relative pathnames.

Here's what the File javadoc says:

> On UNIX systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current user directory. On Microsoft Windows systems, a relative pathname is made absolute by resolving it against the current directory of the drive named by the pathname, if any; if not, it is resolved against the current user directory.

The "current user directory" means the current directory that was in force when the application was launched.  That depends on how the application was launched.  For instance, if you launch from a command shell using `java`, the current directory will be the shell's current directory.  But if you use a launch wrapper script, it may `cd` to somewhere else before launching the JVM.  And so on.

But the bottom line is that if you are going to use relative paths, you need to have the right current directory.

Incidentally, when the JVM starts, the absolute path of the current directory is places in the System Properties object.  You can read the property to find out what the current directory is, but changing the property does NOT change the way that relative paths are resolved by the File API and friends.  AFAIK, there is no way that a pure Java application can reliably change its own current directory.